# How to format cells to display 1.67 as 1h 40 min in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to calculate time in excel - 50 miles/30mph=1.67h. How can I format cells to display 1h 40min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing calculation then you can do an additional division by 24, e.g.

`=50/30/24`

or if you have distance in A2, speed in B2 use this formula in C2

`=A2/B2/24`

Ensure that you custom format the result cell as [h]:mm

Answer (score 1):

Serega welcome to the forum. Here is a formula you could use:

```
="Decimal Value Location"/24
```

for example `=A1/24`

You will need to format the formula cell to Custom, `hh:mm` and you should be good to go!